# Need to pass data to child component using Form group in angular 2?

Tags: angular

Am trying to pass data using @Input from parent to child component, where parent and child both are using form group and the control are accessed by the child component by @Input, whereas if I need to pass some data to the child component using @input decorator am getting Error

**Parent Component.html**

```
 <rulebuilder [mydata]="ruledata" [generalrulegroup]="editRulesFrmGrp.controls.generalRule.controls[i]"></rulebuilder>
```

**Child Component.ts**

```
 @Input('generalrulegroup')

@Input()mydata:any;
```

**Console Error**

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'generalrulegroup' since it isn't a known property of 'modifygeneralrulebuilder'. ("<modifygeneralrulebuilder [mydata]="modifyRuleJson" [ERROR ->][generalrulegroup]="editRulesFrmGrp.controls.generalRule.controls[i]"></modifygeneralrulebuilde"): RuleEditComponent@108:128
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:103798:27)
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:9270:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:27281:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65409:68)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65292:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65292:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65175:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:164194:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:164076:43)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Input('generalrulegroup') generalrulegroup: any;
```

You need to declare it in the current component.

Comment: current component means child or parent component

Comment: you are saying it for generalrulegroup but I need it for mydata

Comment: Your error regards `generalrulegroup` and, therefore, I saw it isn't actually declared. With current component I mean ChildComponent. I don't see full componets code so is hard to me to see what's happening overall.

Comment: is it possible to pass data to child component with Form group any link

Comment: You can pass data from parent to child with @Input(). Here is the link: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: if I use as per your answer am getting the following error
Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
do you have any idea on this

Comment: Is FormGroup properly added to your component's module?

Comment: cant get you, how I can add the FormGroup to my Module, as far as I know I can add components and pipes to the component module, please correct me if am wrong